# Change the JRE/JDK used by tomcat6

Tags: elementary-os, tomcat, jdk

I **need to change the JRE used by my tomcat6 server**, because I've a JSP App which has compiled classes whith `JDK 1.8.0_45`.

Then since I had `JRE 1.8.0_40` (and being it used by tomcat), I got a faulire at runtime in my JSP App:

```
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

So I've installed `JRE 1.8.0_45`, just dowloading it, then extract and move to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_45/
```

And then updated to use it (as you can see here, sorry since it's in Spanish):

[image: Update-alternatives]

So I just reboot the computer, and then looked for which JRE is using tomcat... but found something like this (sorry if it's not the best way to look at it, was the easier way I think):

```
ps -aux | grep tomcat
```

[image: Tomcat6 execution]

As you can see, the first "line" in the output of grep is the execution of tomcat (isn't it?) **but it seems to be using JDK instead of JRE**. And plus that, it's using `JDK1.8.0_40`, while I'm using `JDK1.8.0_45` in this same PC when building my App:

[image: JDK used by me]

And if we check the JDK options, the selected one hasn't a version specified, so I don't know if there's something wrong about it:

[image: Alternatives JDK]

So this is my problem, I just wonder **how can I change the JDK/JRE version used by tomcat to u45**.

I need to fix all this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably fix this by setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `/etc/default/tomcat6` (I'm assuming elementary OS still has the Debian/Ubuntu Tomcat package).

The error you're getting is rather surprising though, I wouldn't expect to have errors regarding `Map$Entry` when switching between JDK 1.8.0_40 and 1.8.0_45.

Comment: I've tried that already and didn't work. I'll try again and tell you if it does.

Comment: I've tried it again @StephenKitt. I think tomcat is starting with the new JDK but doesn't work fine don't know why. Anyway your answer is correct, so I will create another one in stackoverflow. Thanks so much